# Парсинг компаний с РБК

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Меня попросили помочь с парсингом компаний отсюда https://www.rbc.ru/rbc500/ в excel таблицу. Мне успешно удалось загрузить данные через curl, обойдя защиту под гугловским прокси. Но проблема в том, что при первоначальной загрузке страницы отображается только первые 40+ компаний, для того, чтобы отобразить остальные нужно нажать кнопку «Весь список», а сэмулировать нажатие ссылки средствами curl, очевидно, невозможно. Такая же ситуация и с годом (нужны данные за 2017-2019). Скорее всего, нажатие соответствующих ссылок по итогу должно через ajax вести по ссылкам типа https://www.rbc.ru/rbc500?param=value, которые в итоге и надо парсить, но отыскать это в js-коде сайта оказалось совершенно невозможным. Может быть, кто-то из более опытных коллег сумеет помочь в решение этой сперва казалось бы простенькой задачи. Заранее спасибо.

**UPD.**

Так, благодаря комментатору ниже, первая часть проблемы решена и ссылка с ajax найдена, но вот содержимое оттуда подгружается с огромным количеством спецсимволов, что делает невозможным дальнейший парсинг. Как можно от этого избавиться?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также добавляю сюда код парсера.

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init ("https://www.rbc.ru/rbc500/ajax?&limit=1000&year=2019&field=profloss_net_infographic&sort=netgain&spec=&_=1583392428737");
$fp = fopen ("test_parser.html", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "google");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose ($fp);
echo readfile('test_parser.html');
//include htmlspecialchars('test_parser.html');
?>
```

Данные со спецсимволами находятся по ссылке https://www.rbc.ru/rbc500/ajax?&limit=1000&year=2019&field=profloss_net_infographic&sort=netgain&spec=&_=1583392428737

Comment: Искать нужно не в js коде, а на вкладке network в инструментах разработчика в браузере

Comment: Спасибо! Удалось найти нужную ссылку. Теперь требуется решить проблему с тем, что полученный результат содержит экранированные символы.

Comment: stripcslashes, json_decode, htmlspecialchars_decode не даёт никакого эффекта

Comment: @juggernaut, добавьте, пожалуйста, в сам вопрос пример тех данных с спецсимволами

Comment: Они находятся по ссылке https://www.rbc.ru/rbc500/ajax?&limit=1000&year=2019&field=profloss_net_infographic&sort=netgain&spec=&_=1583392428737

Comment: @juggernaut, пожалуйста, добавляйте @ к нику, чтобы тот, к кому обращались, увидел уведомление. Хоть по ссылке есть данные, она может стать не актуальной

Comment: @gil9red есть ли способ сейчас, пока ссылка актуальна, как-то избавиться от лишних слэшей, кавычек и прочих спецсимволов при парсинге?

Comment: @juggernaut, этот сайт создан как база данных вопросов и решений, поэтому вопросы (и ответы), чей смысл существует исключительно по ссылкам, являются плохими и могут быть закрыты до добавления большего количества деталей. Т.е. создавая вопросы желательно предоставить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Answer (score -1):

[image: Результат]

Я буду использовать guzzle, для того чтобы его использовать ,установите guzzle командой `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0` ,
по ссылке получаем все компании за один раз [500 компаний](https://www.rbc.ru/rbc500/ajax?&limit=1000&year=2019&sort_order=desc&field=profloss_net_infographic&sort=netgain&spec=&_=1583398611013) , все это представлено в формате json поэтому его нужно будет преобразовать.

```
<style type="text/css">
//Импортируем стили из рбк
@import url(https://s.rbk.ru/v2_emitbase_static/emitbase- 
3.1.7/styles/build/_main.css);
</style>
<?

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//Используем namespace GuzzleHttp
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    //указываем ссылку на 500 компаний

    "base_uri" => "https://www.rbc.ru/rbc500/ajax?&limit=1000&year=2019&sort_order=desc&field=profloss_net_infographic&sort=netgain&spec=&_=1583398611013"
]);

// берем полученные данные
$response = $client->get('')->getBody()->getContents();

//превращаем json в ассоциативный массив
$companies = json_decode($response,true);

// далее в цикле выводим все html элементы которые есть в json и получаем красивый вид т.к мы подключили стили рбк
foreach ($companies['items'] as $value) {
    echo $value['html'];
}
```